# PlaySound in C beeps but does not play wav file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, playsound

In C, my `PlaySound` is not throwing any errors... but instead of playing the file I want, it just beeps.

Any suggestions?

I tried :

```
PlaySound("song1.wav", NULL, SND_ALIAS | SND_APPLICATION);
```

And:

```
PlaySound("song1.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

But I got the same result.

Comment: what have you done? show us some code. AND also tell us where your song1.wav resides.

Comment: Are you sure it can find the "song1.wav" file? Maybe the current working directory is not correct? To make sure, maybe you can try to specify a full path name in the PlaySound call.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using relative path like you have done:

```
PlaySound("song1.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Use an absolute path like:

```
PlaySound("F:\\path\\to\\your\\song\\song1.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from PlaySound API description, at msdn.microsoft.com:

> `PlaySound` searches the following directories for sound files: the
>   current directory; the Windows directory; the Windows system
>   directory; directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable; and
>   the list of directories mapped in a network.
>
> If the function cannot find the specified sound and the
>   `SND_NODEFAULT` flag is not specified, `PlaySound` uses the default
>   system event sound instead(In your case the BEEP).
>
> If the function can find neither the system default entry nor the
>   default sound, it makes no sound and returns `FALSE`.

So, add the file directory path into the `PATH` environment variable in windows. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Or use a full path instead of a relative path.

Comment: OP's question suggests that he is using relative paths. So, answered according to that. Although, absolute paths are always good, but less flexible to changes in paths(a sceanrio, where a massive source code change will need to be done everytime the file path changes, which would be avoided by simply adding or removing a path in the PATH environment variable and using relative paths).

Comment: I suggest staying away from the `PATH` environment.  Too many things already pollute it as it is. There is no reason not to use a full path in your code instead. If you are worried about the path changing, store the path in a variable that you assign at app startup and update if needed, then you can append relative filenames to that value when operating on files.

Comment: @Remy: Agreed and That's what I would suggest, too. I intended to get the simplest working solution for OP, without altering the code at all. To make a point that there's probably no problem with OP's code and only specific to the referenced PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I was in trouble with same situation like OP's and found solution for me.
My solution is eliminating meta data of wav file.

[Post (japanese)](http://blog.fujiu.jp/2015/08/protools-first-wavplaysound.html?spref=tw)

Referring to post, PlaySound() API can't play some wav files that are exported with famous audio tool. (such as ProTools, CUBASE, StudioOne etc..)

And eliminating meta data makes it worked.
in blog post, he opened some 'troubling' wave file with [SoundEngine(japanese)](http://soundengine.jp/software/soundengine/) and just 'save as' new file to eliminate wav RIFF meta information.

Comment: sorry for poor english, but I hope someone can make it work, so I did my best :):)