# C++ Play video audio in console application

Tags: c++, windows, audio, video

I've been working on a C++ application that plays a different video depending on what a user did. So Far I've worked with OpenCV to only play the video, since I need to do some changes on the video on real time. Since OpenCV doesn't play sound, I need to use a different library to play the sound independently. So far I tried FFMPEG, but I couldn't get it work, since I'm not experienced on working on C++ (At least in a computer with external libraries, I normally programm it on microcontrollers).

The sound doesn't need to sync with the video and it also only should run on Windows. What is my best option?

Thanks.

Comment: main ability of opencv is to process the frames, not to I/O them. I would use Qt + phonon for this. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/multimedia-examples.html

Comment: I' using OpenCV to process Frames, as I need to process a video in real time. However, OpenCV does not process audio and I need to play it too, exactly how it is in the video.

Comment: opencv can I/O video as image data -actually it uses ffmpeg at lower layer- however its main ability is to process them. For audio it has no capability.

Comment: As I said, I actually only want to run the audio of the video, I don't want to process it.

Answer (score 0):

If it does only need to work for Windows, the [WINAPI function `PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should fulfil your requirements.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "mmsystem.h"

void play()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("sound.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME); // plays sound.wav once
}
```

To make this work you need to link against `winmm.lib`.

If your file name is not ASCII you should use `PlaySoundA` (ANSI) or `PlaySoundW` (unicode) instead.

[See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980801/playsound-in-c-beeps-but-does-not-play-wav-file) if the sound is not played properly.

Comment: I did what you said, but for some reason it plays the "wrong" sound of windows (I must have made something wrong). here's the code:

PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/Ricardo/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/SomEVideo/SomEVideo/KinectAudio-02-23-32.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME); // plays sound.wav once

Comment: I can't really help you, as I do not understand what "wrong sound of windows" it is playing. You should probably make a new question out of that.

Comment: Here's exactly what I did: First included the headers on stdafx.h, then put only this line of code in the main funtion to test it PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/Ricardo/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/SomEVideo/SomEVideo/KinectAudio-02-23-32.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);. After this, I linked winmm.lib in the project properties. When I runned the program, instead of playing the wav sound I wanted it played this wav sound: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45453297/Windows%20Background.wav

Comment: @RicardoAlves from the linked specification: "SND_FILENAME The pszSound parameter is a file name. **If the file cannot be found, the function plays the default sound** unless the SND_NODEFAULT flag is set."

Comment: @RicardoAlves isn't windows using Backslashes? Shouldn't the path be: "C:\Users\Ricardo\[etc...]\KinectAudio-02-23-32.wav"

Comment: @RicardoAlves go ask a new question with that problem, I will probably not be able to help you, sorry I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I already tried it. PlaySoundA doesn't even in recognized by the compiler, but PlaySoundW does the same as PlaySound. I really have no clue on what to do next.

Comment: @RicardoAlves try if it does work with a relative path. Your path is probably wrong.

Comment: I've oppened a new wuestion as you said and it explains what I've tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654961/c-play-audio-in-windows

Comment: The wav file I was testing for some reason doesn't work. I tried with another wav file and it does work. I then tried to run the sound file from my video and it also doesn't work. Any ohter solution to play sound from a video?